# Where is a logical place to put a file flag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a Ruby on Rails application, where would the most logical place be to put a "file flag."

I am attempting to externalize configuration and allow the presence of a file to be the deciding factor on whether or not something shows on the webapp.

Right now, I have a file here:

```
lib/
  deployment_enabled
```

Model **deployment.rb**

```
class Deployment...
  ...
  def deployment_enabled?
    Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/deployment_enabled"].any?
  end
end
```

Now this works of course, but i'm not sure this follows the MVC paradigms, since the `lib` directory should consist of scripts.  I could put it in `config`, but again - not sure it belongs there as rails uses this for rails specific configuration, not necessarily the webapp.

I could of course put this in our database, but that require a new table to be created, and that seems unnecessary.

*Where's the most logical place to put this flag file?  Does Rails have a directory that's created during the generation to put these sort of files?*

Comment: Is this configuration 'flag' is intended to be changed at runtime? I mean add/remove the file once the app is started?

Comment: that's right, @ehoffmann.  if we wanted to immediately re-enable it, just create the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the Rails `tmp` directory for this purpose. Then:

```
File.exist?("#{Rails.root}/tmp/deployment_enabled")
```

Phusion Passenger use this kind of mechanism too.
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/basics/ruby/reloading_code.html#tmp-always_restart-txt

Comment: hm... tmp does seem like a reasonable place

Comment: I can say now that this definitely is the most logical place to put it.  reasons:  1. tmp directory does not get reset when the server restarts.  2. tmp dir is already added to most .gitignore files, so when the file is added ,it does not get added to SCM

Comment: A runtime invocation of a filesystem call for a configuration value that should be stored in the application's memory? This is very bad practice. Filesystem calls are expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you follow the [Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/config) guidelines and keep your code separate from your configuration. In this case you are really talking about a simple boolean value, and the presence of the file is just the mechanism you use to define the value. This should be done instead through an environment variable.

Something like:

```
DEPLOYMENT_ENABLED=1 RAILS_ENV=production rails server
```

You would then use an initializer in Rails to detect the value:

```
# config/initializers/deployment.rb
foo if ENV['DEPLOYMENT_ENABLED']
```

The value can still be modified at runtime, e.g., `ENV['DEPLOYMENT_ENABLED'] = 0`.

Comment: I'm not sure environment variable are the best way to manage the OP case.   He want to be able to update the flag at runtime.  With the solution above  you'll encounter many issues: Changes to the ENV at runtime will be reseted between each application restart; You have to create the feature to update the ENV at runtime (controller action...); You cannot easily automate the flag update process (or at last not as easily as a `touch tmp/filename`). IMHO, ENV should be considered as constant and not be modified at runtime.

Comment: On the contrary: the filesystem is not under control of Rails. The application configuration stored in the environment is under the exclusive control of Rails. Every example you give for why it should be done with a file goes against best practices for app development. Here is the simplest reason not to do it with a file: it doesn't scale beyond a single instance. Bad practices are bad for a reason, even if they seem sensible in a vacuum.

Comment: `tmp` IS under control of Rails framework (we do not talk about `/tmp`). It is used for caching, PID... and many popular gems use it too. It is scalable since every Rails app instance has its own `tmp`. It is also a common idiom on Unix system to use files as flag. Modifying an environment variable at runtime is not relevant for the OP case: It is not persisted across restarts and, in fact, it is just like using a 'global variable' which is a 'bad practice'. That why ENV should be considered as constant.

Comment: `tmp` is NOT under control of Rails, it is under control of the operating system, and the filesystem in production environments is typically read-only and owned by `nobody`. That's why these are called best practices, because if you follow them you won't have to re-engineer your solution when you realize it doesn't scale beyond your laptop.

Comment: Ok we'll never agree! I'll let future visitors make their own opinion and exit this discussion here.